# Visual Studio 2017 will not compile xamarin cross platform project

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am getting a bunch of errors

> "The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

What I have tried is updating the Xamarin.Android.Support packages but it fails to update to 26.1.0.1. Current version installed is 25.4.0.2.

I also tried Clean Solution and Build Solution, but no success. I believe I am only getting these errors on Cross Platform mode because I was able to compile and run on Android project only. How do I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Even System also not found, some error on you VS install

Comment: Did you restore NuGet packages? Is your Visual Studio updated to latest stable?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I tried Restore NuGet packages and that seemed to have fixed the problem. It is the latest Visual Studio update. I guess this is some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the usual things. Clean the build. Restore Nuget Packages. I tried to clear the Nuget cache via the Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Nuget Package Settings, but after a long wait I got an error. Out of desperation I decided to update the Nuget Package Automapper from version 7 to 7.01. As far as the errors were concerned Automapper was completely irrelevant. And yet it worked, I could suddenly compile again.
Amazing.
Maybe this cleared the Nuget cache? 
Well next time this happens I will do something similar - maybe change the Automapper version back to 7 again and see if that works.
It did this time.